# When does one need to be careful not to incite the Satan?

Tags: words, tractate-brachot, speech-talking, satan, danger

The Gemara ([Berachos 19a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.19a.20-21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) learns out from Yeshayah 1:9-2:1, that one should not say that something bad could have happened to him, so as not to incite the Satan.

The question is: doesn’t David Hamelech speak in a similar manner in [Tehillim chapter 124](//www.sefaria.org/Psalms.124); also in Asher Yatzar we say ״שאם יסתם אחד מהם…אי אפשר להתקיים…״?

Comment: [related](/q/83748)